# centos6.2 64 php-fpm start error

Tags: imagick, php

error message:

> /usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm start
>   /usr/local/php/sbin/php-fpm: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/imagick.so: undefined symbol: MagickWandGenesis

Answer (score 0):

This would appear that your Imagick installation is fubar'd. I'd recommend try to re-install this piece of software.

You can download the Imagick here -> http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

1) Untar the file

2) /path/to/phpize

3)  ./configure \
    --with-php-config=/path/to/php-config \
    --with-imagick

4) make && make install

5) You may need to add extension=imagick.so to your php.ini but it sounds like you may already have this.

If this does not work for you, you can simply remove the extension=imagick.so from your php.ini and PHP-FPM should start up without any troubles. You just won't have Imagick support until you fix it.